# Problem on coloring nodes with [fill=black!\pgfmathresult] in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, pgfmath

I tried to use tikz to fill nodes with colors according to values in an array file, but I failed to fill nodes with right color when fixing node position by [at (a,b)]:

```
\begin{document}
The data in the 6,3 position of the file is \arqa[6,3]\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,fill=black!50,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[shape=rectangle,draw=black,fill=black!\pgfmathresult]
\pgfmathparse{\arqa[6,3]}
\node  at (6,3)[vertex,fill=black!\pgfmathresult] (G-6,4);
\node  at (6,4)[vertex,fill=black!50.2] (G-6,5);
\node [vertex,fill=black!\pgfmathresult] (G-6,6);
\end{document}
```

The output pdf is like this [image]

So the node "**\node  at (6,3)[vertex,fill=black!\pgfmathresult] (G-6,4);**" does not fill with black color with "black!50.20", but the node "**\node [vertex,fill=black!\pgfmathresult] (G-6,6);**" is filled with right color without the [**at (6,3)**] position. Can anyone help me?

Comment: please eaxtend your code snippet to complete small compilable document.  command `\arqa` is not defined ... welcome to.tex.se!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tikz performs some calculations when using `\node`, which then overwrites the number stored in `\pgfmathresult`. Below some code that should work (where I've added a small table to define a value for `\arqa`):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{table.dat}
    0   25
    75  100
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{table.dat}{\arqa}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{1}\of{\arqa}
\pgfmathsetmacro\result{\pgfplotsretval}

The data in the 6,3 position of the file is \result\\

\begin{tikzpicture}
%\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,fill=black!50,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[shape=rectangle,draw=black,fill=black!\result]
\node  at (6,3)[vertex,fill=black!\result]{};
\node  at (6,4)[vertex,fill=black!50.2] {};
\node [vertex,fill=black!\result] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```